# Read Multiple files one by one and extract the content based on different variables for each file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, pyshark

I'm new to python i have set for Pcap files in a directory. i should read each file and extract the required data based on differnt variable for each file. i'm using pyshark for parsing pcap.

i have to take csv file column as an input for each filtering file

[image]

for example i have 4 files each in **src- and dst-** so first file i should be filtered by taking 10.272.726.227 only  and for 2nd file 10.272.726.228  etc...

see below,

```
files = os.listdir('./Pcap')
csv_file=pd.read_csv('input.csv')
ip_src = csv_file.SRC_privateIp.tolist()
ip_dst = csv_file.DST_privateIp.tolist()  

for file in files:
    if file.startswith('src-'):
        cap_src = pyshark.FileCapture(file, only_summaries = True)
        for packet in cap_src:
            line=str(packet)
            formattedline = line.split(' ')
            if formattedline[2] == ip_src and formattedline[3] == ip_dst:
                print(formattedline)

    if file.startswith('dst-'):
        cap_src = pyshark.FileCapture(file, only_summaries = True)
        for packet in cap_src:
            line=str(packet)
            formattedline = line.split(' ')
            if formattedline[2] == ip_dst and formattedline[3] == ip_src :
                print(formattedline)
```

I tried to open each file and do processing on each file separately but it is taking all files data in one string. I want each file to open one by one, do processing because each file has different conditions to filter out the necessary. The above code gives an error **This event loop is already running**. i dont know how to proceed further Can anybody help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having an issue understanding your question.  How is the file (csv_file) being used in filtering?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what your question is, but I think you can use `pandas` for `csv` reading, subsetting and manipulations. It is the standard library for this kind of tasks.

[Read csv with pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) or

[Subset a dataframe with pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html)

Comment: i edited my question can please guide how to approach further  @DeveR

Comment: what do you meanwith 'takes all file in one string' ? Can you show what 1 or 2 file looks like (https://kite.com/python/answers/how-to-create-a-pandas-dataframe-from-a-string-in-python)  and what is the expected output (just to have an idea)? Do you want to filter some rows or what?